# How to specify publisher in schema.org's Article structured data?

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org, structured-data

I am trying to use the [Article](https://schema.org/Article) type from schema.org:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
<!-- ... -->
<meta itemprop="publisher" content="MyCorp" />
</article>
```

When validating this piece of HTML with the [Google validator](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), it suggests me to provide the publisher logo. How should I modify the code above to include the URL of the logo?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this, though of course other properties are required for this to meet [Google's requirements](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles) for article features in search results.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<!-- blah blah -->
  <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
    <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <img src="http://www.mycorp.com/logo.jpg"/>
      <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.mycorp.com/logo.jpg">
      <meta itemprop="width" content="400">
      <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="MyCorp">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Schema.org expects an `Organization` item as value for the [`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher) property, but you provide a string value ("MyCorp").

If you want to follow Schema.org’s expectation (which is just a recommendation, not mandatory), you could use something like this:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">

  <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Corporation">
    <span itemprop="name">MyCorp</span>
  </div>

</article>
```

Google might want to see more properties (like `logo`) for the `Organization` item, but these are also not required. Their testing tool just wants to say that you don’t get one of their search results features if you don’t provide a certain set of properties.

Comment: No, `publisher.logo` is a _required_ property for Articles (along with various others), assuming you want Google's article-related SERP features to work. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles

Comment: @GDav: *Required* (by Google) for the specific feature (that’s what my last sentence says), but not required for the well-being of your site/SEO. It’s perfectly fine not to provide this property, e.g. if you don’t want the feature, or because your organization has no logo, or because you can’t provide other properties that are required, too.

Comment: As I say, "required […] assuming you want Google's […] features to work". The question asks _how_ to implement the logo property, not whether or not you should bother. The tangible SEO benefit is access to Google's SERP features for articles, so compliance with their specification seems advisable.